# Automatic pull from remote

Tags: git, deployment

I have a remote repository (on bitbucket) that houses all of our production and staging repositories. When I am on my local development machine and make a commit + push, how can I set my development server (its remotely hosted, sharing the same remote repository) up to automatically know that I pushed, so it does a pull request to pull in the changes that I pushed up to the remote repository?

Is there any easy way to do this? Right now, I am manually SSHing into the development server and pulling, but this is time consuming, and there are times that I forget to do it, and the content team working on the content doesn't get the latest changes.

Are there git hooks available for this, or do I need to write some custom functionality to check the current remote HEAD and pull if it's changed (on a cron job most likely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` is kind of idempotent, so simply launch it in a cron job, no need to check if it's necessary or not.

If you want a smarter solution, use [webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html):

1. Create a webapp that will perform the pull when an URL is called
2. Configure a webhook in bitbucket to call this URL and is triggered by a push event on the repo